# Django - email app

Tags: django, email, django-email

Could you please suggest any available app for sending & managing emails in django?

Comment: maybe you should have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730573/django-to-send-and-receive-email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a detailed comparison here: http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/email/

Answer (score -1):

You can try implement this youself using http://docs.python.org/library/poplib.html and http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example but, if you describe what concrete functionality you need, may be i can suggest some ready Django app for you needs.

Comment: I just want to send the email notifications to certain users whenever there is a add/change in some specific models. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use django's model signals (docs here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/)

Comment: I have just wrote an app which can achieve this. Thanks for the help.